# Tableview not scrolling on the first tap iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I have views hierarchy in Viewcontroller below. First time when I open the view controller my tableview is not scrolling at all even when I tap on tableview it will not recognize my tap. After that It is working fine as expected. I can able to scroll and select cell and working fine. Only first time I am having issue.

I don't have enough reputation so I can't post image.

ViewController -> View -> ScrollView -> View(viewSC) -> TableView -> TableViewCell

Anyone experiencing this kind of behavior.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.viewSC.frameSize;
self.scrollView.contentInset =      UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.HV.frameHeight, 0, 0, 0);
self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.HV.frameHeight, 0, 0, 0);
```

this is the only code added in viewDidLoad. Other than that it is all working fine.

Comment: More info / code, please!

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: What is viewSC? Why do you need a table view to be inside a scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to scroll as soon as the table view is created?  When it comes to `UITableView` manipulation, you have to make sure that it's created and displayed before you try to scroll it.  `UITableView` is picky like that.  If you are loading your view and then you want to scroll the table view, call your code in `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks anyways. Actually, I just figure out. What happen is, when you open the app, the help screen pop up for each View controller. I recently added new functionality and new view controller for that. So when you call first time, it pops up help screen on the top of the view controller. I don't have help screen yet for this view controller so there is empty help screen with clear color that's why it won't scroll at the first and I am dismissing help screen on the tap. Solved it by dismissing the help screen at the first time. Thank you guys for looking into it.